# Querying for DynamoDB items using "contains"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have a DynamoDB table such as

```
TableName: 'Items'
Key: {Hash: 'Id'}
```

Each item has a name and belongs to a customer, so I also have an Index on

```
{Hash: CustomerId, Range:Name}
```

Let's say I have this data:

```
Id    CustomerId    Name
1     18            Milk
2     42            Orange juice
3     42            Apple juice
4     42            Coffee
5     54            Tomato juice
```

Now, I want to query for all items for a particular customer and filter the results for partial names (essentially a search operation). For example, give me all items belonging to customer 42 that contains "juice" in its name (Orange juice and Apple juice are expected results).

If I query for `CustomerId = '42' AND contains(Name, 'juice')` I will get an error saying that `KeyConditionExpression` doesn't support `contains`. I can sort of understand this limitation since `contains` means having to scan all items (within the given hash key), but, well, you *can* query for *all* items with `CustomerId = '42'` which is also a full scan within that hash, so I'm not sure I understand this limitation. Things like `begins_with` are supported just as expected (which makes sense since it's easy to quickly return a subset from a sorted set).

Anyway, so I curse a little bit and say I'll just use a FilterExpression instead and live with the wasted RCU:s, resulting in a query with

```
KeyConditionExpression: CustomerId = '42'
FilterExpression: contains(Name, 'juice')
```

But now I get an error saying that I am not allowed to include primary key attributes in my FilterExpression ("use KeyConditionExpression instead!").

This leaves me in somewhat of a dilemma. I can't filter with `contains` in my `KeyCondition` and I can't filter on `Name` in my `FilterExpression`. Should I have to create a *separate index only on CustomerId* in order to implement my use-case or is there any other way to solve this...?

Comment: How frustrating, and interesting! Creating a whole new index would be expensive. You would be much better off duplicating the Name attribute (so one attribute called NameKey and one just called Name). Then you could use the FilterExpression on the non-key Name field like you were trying in your second attempt. Still rubbish, but less costly.

Comment: Thanks Stu. That did cross my mind, but it felt.. rubbish like you said. It might be the best compromise though. Would be cool to get some official aws response to this, I might copy the post to the aws forums as well.

Comment: How did you manage to finally solve this problem because I am facing the same problem right now

Comment: It's been a while but if my memory serves me right, I ended up doing client side filtering since my data set per customer was fairly small. 

Comment: The key expression should contain both the Hask Key and Sort  Key expression like : KKeyConditionExpression: "CustomerId= :id and begins_with(Name, :name)",  Sorry.. only these expressions are supported for  Key Expression :EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN

Comment: I see begins_with will not work in your case, so you will need to scan for using contains expression. : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

Answer (score 16):

With DynamoDB, I think the best solution is to store the data in the shape you later intend to read.

If you find yourself requiring complex read queries you might have fallen into the trap of expecting DynamoDB to behave like an RDBMS, which it is not. Transform and shape your data on the *write*, keep the read simple.

Answer (score 11):

**DynamoDB** only allow `begin_with()` for **key conditions**. So `contains()` is not supported, but for your case it is possible to arrange the rangeKey in hierarchical order like:

```
CustomerId    Name
18            Milk
42            juice.Orange 
42            juice.Apple
42            Coffee
54            Tomato juice
```

So the query can be structured like

```
KeyConditionExpression: CustomerId = '42' AND Name BEGINS_WITH 'juice'
```

---

**NOTE:**

- The only way to use `contains()` seems to be in **filter expressions**, and filter expressions may only operate on non-keys.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach. If what you need to query for are essentially things like categories, this would probably work. In my particular use-case the data is however more complex, for example finding items with partial URI:s etc, so it wouldn't be possible to rearrange it hierarchically.

Answer (score 3):

For stuff like this you should consider the concepts of *composite keys* and *GSI overloading* and re-design your table to fit your access patterns.

As per https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/

> Use composite attributes. Try to combine more than one attribute to
>   form a unique key, if that meets your access pattern. For example,
>   consider an orders table with customerid+productid+countrycode as the
>   partition key and order_date as the sort key.

So you could do something like designing your table to hold an index of `customerid#name`

Comment: Thanks but not sure how that helps. The only way to use contains seems to be in filter expressions, and filter expressions may only operate on non-keys. If I combine customerId and name into one single string and use it for hash key, I cannot query for all items belonging to a particular customer, and I still cannot use contains. Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

This query behave as like query in relational db

```
database.scan() 
     .filterExpression('begins_with(#name ,:name) or begins_with(#someno,:name)') 
    .expressionAttributeNames({ "#name": "name","#someno":"someno"}) 
    .expressionAttributeValues({ ":name" : data}) 
    .exec().promise();
```

Comment: Not sure if you read the question. I know how queries work, thank you, but I encountered a limitation in DynamoDB due to KeyConditionExpression not supporting contains. Not sure how your answer addresses that.

Comment: Sorry dude my fault

Answer (score 0):

Just duplicate your attribute and apply the filter on it

Answer (score 0):

We can use CONTAINS operator in the query API as below.

```
  Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
  Map<String, String> expression = new HashMap<>();
  expression.put("#ProductName","name");
  expression.put("#Type","type");

  eav.put(":" + Constant.QUERY_VAL, new AttributeValue().withS(productList.get(0).getId()));
  eav.put(":search", new AttributeValue().withS(productText));
  DynamoDBQueryExpression<ProductEntity> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<ProductEntity>()
      .withIndexName(Constant.PRODUCTSLIST_INDEX)
      .withKeyConditionExpression(Constant.PRODUCTLISTID + "=:" + Constant.QUERY_VAL)
      .withFilterExpression(
          "(contains (sku,:search)) OR (contains (brandName,:search)) OR (contains (description,:search)) OR (contains (#Type,:search)) OR (contains (#ProductName,:search))")
      .withExpressionAttributeNames(expression)
      .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav).withScanIndexForward(false).withConsistentRead(false);
  LOGGER.info("Search text {} "+ queryExpression);
  result = dynamoDBMapper.query(ProductEntity.class, queryExpression, conf);
```